# Shrink wrap made some of my model face gone

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shrinkwrap

Im a beginner who just started learning blender i made this model based on some tutorial and end up using shrink wrap for the eye of this model i it bother me because the left eye face is gone after i shrinkwrap it while the right one is still exist like this

[image]

Blend file 
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51731

Edit : 
sorry i was not clear enough, it was supposed to be my eyelid i want to make the outer eyelid adapt the eyeball shape by using shrink wrap then subsurface it

Comment: Instead of shrinkwrap use a texture.

Comment: your object has a lot of shrinkwraps, it's not clear what you're trying to do, it seems complicated and probably useless, could you tell more about the final object?

Comment: sorry i was not clear enough, it was supposed to be my eyelid i want to make the outer eyelid adapt the eyeball shape by using shrink wrap then subsurface it